# LINQ to entites: How to return the latest order number for a customer

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Suppose we have the typical `Customers` and `Orders` relationship, where a `Customer` can have several `Orders`, and the `Orders` contain the `CustomerId` as FK.

I think this code returns the whole Order entity for the latest order:

```
    Order latestOrder = (from o in context.Orders 
                         //where conditions or joins to be included here                                                    
                         group o by o.CustomerId into grp
                         select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.OrderDate).First())
```

How can I return only the `OrderNumber`, of type `string`, instead of the whole entity? (or empty if it has none)

```
    string latestOrderNumber = (?)
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `Select(g => g.OrderNumber)` before `First()` And you need to call `FirstOrDefault` again in order to retrieve a single `OrderNumber` rather than a `IQueryable<string>`

```
string latestOrderNumber = (from o in context.Orders 
                            group o by o.CustomerId into grp
                            select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.OrderDate)
                                     .Select(g => g.OrderNumber)
                                     .FirstOrDefault()
                           ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
 Order latestOrder = (from o in context.Orders 
                      //where conditions or joins to be included here                                                    
                      group o by o.CustomerId into grp
                      select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.OrderDate).FirstOrDefault());
```

It's a good practice to use the `FirstOrDefault`. If not any order found, then the result is null. Then you check if the result is not null and you just read the property of the returned item.

```
if(latestOrder!=null)
    lastOrdeNumber = lastOrder.OrderNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Hope it can help you!

```
var result = context.Orders.OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderDate)
            .GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId)
            .Select(grp => grp.First().OrderNumber);
```